# Erro em código PHP - SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php

Estou tentando listar as categorias e subcategorias presentes no banco de dados mas o seguinte erro é apontado:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ''loja_categorias' ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lojacurso\classes\Site.class.php:8 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lojacurso\classes\Site.class.php(8):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lojacurso\pages\categoria.php(13): Site->getMenu() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lojacurso\index.php(20):
>   include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lojacurso\classes\Site.class.php on line 8

O código é esse:

```
<?php

class Site extends BD{

    public function getMenu(){
        $pegar_categorias = "SELECT * FROM 'loja_categorias' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $executar = self::conn()->prepare($pegar_categorias);
        $executar->execute();

        if ($executar->rowCont() == 0) {
            # não faz nada pois não há categorias
        }else{
            while ($categoria = $executar->fetchObject()) {
                echo '<li><a href="'.PATH.'/categoria/'.$categoria->slug.'">'.$categoria->titulo.'';

                    $pegar_subcategorias = "SELECT * FROM 'loja_subcategorias' WHERE id_cat = ?";
                    $executar_sub = self::conn()->prepare($pegar_subcategorias);
                    $executar_sub->execute(array($categoria->id));
                    if ($executar_sub->rowCont() == 0) {
                        echo '</li>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<ul>';
                        while ($subcategoria == $executar_sub->fetchObject()) {
                            echo '<li><a href=" '.PATH.'/categoria/'.$categoria->slug.'/'.$subcategoria->slug.' ">'.$subcategoria->titulo.'</a></li>';
                        }//termina while subcategoria
                        echo '</ul></li>';

                    }//termina else dos resultados da subcategoria
            }//termina while das categorias
        }//primeiro else
    }//TERMINA FUNÇÃO getMenu

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tire as aspas simples do seu `SELECT`, ficando assim:

```
$pegar_categorias = "SELECT * FROM loja_categorias ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Outra alternativa é trocar as aspa simples pelo crase:

```
$pegar_categorias = "SELECT * FROM `loja_categorias` ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: Quando tiro aponta o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::rowCont() in C:\caminho\classes\Site.class.php on line 10"

Comment: Vi aqui o erro de grafia :D

Comment: "Count" e não "cont" como estava